# Jupyter Notebook Toggle Scrolling using Magic Command

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a magic command that if ran in a specific cell, will toggle the scrolling of this particular cell's output only?

If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Tried running the following at the start of the cell:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 9999;
```

But received the error

```
Javascript error adding output!
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry, meant the cell output